# Use XPath to scrape elements which do not contain a certain child element

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

For a scraper I am looking to get a list of all elements on a page, which do not contain a certain child element. The DOM looks something like this

```
<scrape>
      <div id='123'>
          <span>test</span>
      </div>
</scrape>
<scrape>
      <div id='1234'>
          <span>test</span>
      </div>
</scrape>
<scrape>
      <div id='12345'>
          <span>test</span>
          <span>don't include</span>
      </div>
</scrape>
```

What I need to do is, my list needs to contain all **scrape** elements which do not contain a span with text don't include.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
//scrape[not(.//span[text()='don't include'])]
```

Literally:
Element(s) with tag name `scrape` **not** having inside it (child element) with `span` tag name and `text` with value `don't include`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did the trick

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could help you :)